# sarxos webcam-capture-live-streaming example error: package us.sosia.video.stream.agent.ui does not exist

Tags: java, webcam-capture

I want to make a webcam capture software and a stream software using sarxos's webcam library. Wanting to understand the examples first i don't know what to change or add in order to go past this error at import us.sosia.
package us.sosia.video.stream.agent.ui does not exist
package us.sosia.video.stream.handler 
Maybe i have to make a Marvin project and change the pow.xml file but i don't know how to do this and still add my sarxos library to the Marvin project using NetBeans.

first class is StreamServer:

```
package us.sosia.video.stream.agent;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;


public class StreamServer {

    /**
     * @author kerr
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Webcam.setAutoOpenMode(true);
        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        Dimension dimension = new Dimension(320, 240);
        webcam.setViewSize(dimension);

        StreamServerAgent serverAgent = new StreamServerAgent(webcam, dimension);
        serverAgent.start(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 20000));
    }

}
```

Second class is StreamClient:

```
package us.sosia.video.stream.agent;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import us.sosia.video.stream.agent.ui.SingleVideoDisplayWindow;
import us.sosia.video.stream.handler.StreamFrameListener;

public class StreamClient {
    /**
     * @author kerr
     * */
    private final static Dimension dimension = new Dimension(320,240);
    private final static SingleVideoDisplayWindow displayWindow = new SingleVideoDisplayWindow("Stream example",dimension);
    protected final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StreamClient.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //setup the videoWindow
        displayWindow.setVisible(true);

        //setup the connection
        logger.info("setup dimension :{}",dimension);
        StreamClientAgent clientAgent = new StreamClientAgent(new StreamFrameListenerIMPL(),dimension);
        clientAgent.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 20000));
    }


    protected static class StreamFrameListenerIMPL implements StreamFrameListener{
        private volatile long count = 0;
        @Override
        public void onFrameReceived(BufferedImage image) {
            logger.info("frame received :{}",count++);
            displayWindow.updateImage(image);
        }

    }


}
```

I need a way to go past this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your first 2 lines in both files are:

`package us.sosia.video.stream.agent;`

This means that these files should be in the following path
"/us/sosia/video/stream/agent/"

Remove this line from both files.